# recyclerview item showing showing empty white screen in navigation drawer fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, navigation-drawer

I am developing news and I have implemented recyclerview with search view in navigation drawer fragment however recyclerview item in navigation drawer showing empty white screen.
 I am getting two ending point in fragment class and below my root URL.

```
private static final String ROOT_URL = "https://newsapi.org";
```

below my first ending point where I am getting top headlines.

```
 @GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-sport&apiKey=my-api-key")
    Call<SportNews> getArticles();
```

below second ending point where I am getting everything

```
 @GET("/v2/everything?apiKey=my-api-key")
    Call<Search> getSearchViewArticles(@Query("q") String q);
```

below BBCSportsFragment class where I have implemented RecyclerView and SearchView

```
public class BBCSportFragment extends Fragment implements ArticleAdapter.ClickListener {

public static List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

public static List<Article> origArticleList = new ArrayList<>();

@ActivityContext
public Context activityContext;
Search search;
@ApplicationContext
public Context mContext;

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
BBCSportFragmentComponent bbcSportFragmentComponent;
BBCFragmentContextModule bbcFragmentContextModule;
private SportNews sportNews;
private static ArticleAdapter articleAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bbcsport, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    SportInterface sportInterface = SportClient.getApiService();
    Call<SportNews> call = sportInterface.getArticles();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SportNews>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SportNews> call, Response<SportNews> response) {
            if (response == null) {
                sportNews = response.body();
                if (sportNews != null && sportNews.getArticles() != null) {
                    articleList.addAll(sportNews.getArticles());

                }
                articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(articleList, sportNews);
                ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;
                applicationComponent = (ApplicationComponent) MyApplication.get(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getApplicationContext();
                bbcSportFragmentComponent = (BBCSportFragmentComponent) DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().contextModule(new ContextModule(getContext())).build();
                bbcSportFragmentComponent.injectBBCSportFragment(BBCSportFragment.this);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(applicationComponent));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SportNews> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


    SportInterface searchInterface = SportClient.getApiService();
    Call<Search> searchCall = searchInterface.getSearchViewArticles("q");
    searchCall.enqueue(new Callback<Search>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Search> call, Response<Search> response) {
            search = response.body();

            if (search != null && search.getArticles() != null) {
                articleList.addAll(search.getArticles());
                origArticleList.clear();
                origArticleList.addAll(search.getArticles());
            }

            articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(articleList, search);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Search> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


    return view;


}

private Context getContext(ApplicationComponent applicationComponent) {
    return null;
}

public static void doFilter(String searchQuery) {
    searchQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase();
    articleList.clear();
    for (Article article : origArticleList) {
        final String text = article.getTitle();
        if (text.equals(searchQuery))
            articleList.add(article);
    }
    articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

below adapter class

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

public static final String urlKey = "urlKey";
List<Article> articles;

private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private ClipData myClip;


public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> articles, SportNews sportNews) {
    this.articles = articles;


}

public ArticleAdapter(ClickListener clickListener) {
}

public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> articleList, Search search) {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ArticleAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_list, null);
    return new ArticleAdapter.CustomViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull edgar.yodgorbek.sportnews.adapter.ArticleAdapter.CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int position) {
    Article article = articles.get(position);
    SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date d = new Date();
    try {
        d = input.parse(article.getPublishedAt());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String formatted = output.format(d);
    customViewHolder.articleTime.setText(formatted);
    customViewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(article.getSource().getName());
    customViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(article.getTitle());
    Picasso.get().load(article.getUrlToImage()).into(customViewHolder.articleImage);
    customViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("urlKey", article.getUrl());

        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

    });
    customViewHolder.articleShare.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String articleDescription = article.getDescription();
        String articleTitle = article.getTitle();
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, articleDescription);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, articleTitle);
        v.getContext().startActivity((Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using")));


    });

    customViewHolder.articleFavorite.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


        myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", customViewHolder.articleTitle.getText().toString());
        myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (articles == null) return 0;
    return articles.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.articleAuthor)
    TextView articleAuthor;
    @BindView(R.id.articleTitle)
    TextView articleTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.articleImage)
    ImageView articleImage;
    @BindView(R.id.articleTime)
    TextView articleTime;
    @BindView(R.id.articleShare)
    ImageButton articleShare;
    @BindView(R.id.articleFavorite)
    ImageButton articleFavorite;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


    }
}


}
```

below main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

following [screeshot of recyclerview item in navgation drawer fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj2E1.png)

Comment: You're exposing your api key to whole world. Remove that from your question.

Comment: You can add the JSON array that you're getting instead of exposing your API key to whole world.

Comment: @VedprakashWagh thanks I have removed my api key

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, but it seems like you are calling both APIs at once. 
One for getting all data and another one for getting filtered data which contain some string (E.g. In your code you are having "q").

You need to remove below lines from onCreateView of your Fragment. Only call it after click on search icon. And replace the parameter "q" in **searchInterface.getSearchViewArticles("q");** with the string value which you will get from the search box.

```
    SportInterface searchInterface = SportClient.getApiService();
    Call<Search> searchCall = searchInterface.getSearchViewArticles("q");
    searchCall.enqueue(new Callback<Search>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Search> call, Response<Search> response) {
            search = response.body();

            if (search != null && search.getArticles() != null) {
                articleList.clear();
                articleList.addAll(search.getArticles());
            }

            if(articleAdapter != null){
                articleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                articleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(articleList, search);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Search> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: ASADARIYA where I have to initialize are recyclerview and adapter here

Comment: You don't need to initialise adapter and recyclerView again. You have already initialised it before on response of first api call. So just update the list and notify adapter for new changes.

Comment: it is still showing empty screen can you eleborate your answer again

Comment: That means the first API isn't giving any response. And that's why your adapter wasn't initialising. I have updated the code, Check with that once.

Comment: it is still showing empty white screen what your suggestion where I am making mistake

Comment: can I call first app and show that api after that implement search api and showing then second api

Comment: can you check I have updated ending points I have been doing in 3 days

Comment: you told that  I have to d replace the parameter "q" in searchInterface.getSearchViewArticles("q"); with the string value which you will get from the search box how can I implement that can you eloborate with coding sample thanks before hand for answer